# Why does bootstrap grid improperly stack these elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

The third element in my grid is not breaking to the left side, instead it is breaking to the right. I believe this is because the columns are not the same height. I cannot simply attach 2 rows because the way the code is built, it should appear as 1x4, 2x2, then 4x1. I do not want to resort to showing and hiding rows depending on the screen size through javascript or css because I would rather have the grid system work the way it should. Attached is a sample of my code for reference.

```
        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: ">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="background-color: red;">
            <div class="feature-box">
                <div class="feature-item"></div>
                <p class="sub-title">Better Customer Relationships</p>
                <p class="text">Personalized emails connect you with your customers.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="background-color: red;">
            <div class="feature-box">
                <div class="feature-item"></div>
                <p class="sub-title">Set it and Forget It</p>
                <p class="text">Set up a Jaynote campaign once, and automatically engage with every customer.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="background-color: red;">
            <div class="feature-box">
                <div class="feature-item"></div>
                <p class="sub-title">Easy to Use</p>
                <p class="text">Simple management panel shows you exactly what to do.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="background-color: red;">
            <div class="feature-box">
                <div class="feature-item"></div>
                <p class="sub-title">Guaranteed Results</p>
                <p class="text">90 Day money-back guarantee if you are not completely satisfied with your results.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: improper stacking]

Comment: I can think of 2 solutions you can try. 1 Use bootstrap 4 as it uses flex container things like this should be fixed. 2 Use an invisible <p> or something like that to make the heights equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried applying a `.clearfix` every 2 `col-sm-6` (full 12 columns row) elements:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="feature-box">
        <div class="feature-item"></div>
        <p class="sub-title">Better Customer Relationships</p>
        <p class="text">Personalized emails connect you with your customers.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="feature-box">
        <div class="feature-item"></div>
        <p class="sub-title">Set it and Forget It</p>
        <p class="text">Set up a Jaynote campaign once, and automatically engage with every customer.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- apply clearfix -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: I applied this and in large window size, it creates a 4x4 in what seems to be a col-6. I will continue to experiment with this clear fix until i can get something to work.

Comment: set it display: block only on sm breakpoint (≥768px) with @media query.

Comment: i did exactly that before you wrote this. Didn't want to resort to a media query but why not.