# Why is my bootstrap columns behaving unexpectedly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to fix my columns on my structure of my content for a while now with no luck. I have researched column behaviours on bootstrap documentation without any real change on how the resulting view of my page is looking.

I have intended for the content to be in rows of 4 however there is space in between random content in each row except for the top row and no matter what I have tried it doesn't fix the layout. I think it is a bootstrap problem but have been unable for a few months to fix the problem.

[Main Page of Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR0kR.jpg)

home.phtml

```
<?php require('template/header.phtml') ?>   <div class="container">         <div class="row">       <!-- Start of Col Div -->
        <div class="col-md-12">             <!--/.Panel for Comics -->          <!-- Single button -->          <!-- Count for Comics -->                       <?php           if(count($comics)){             ?>          </br> 
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-green"><h3 class="panel-title">My Comics</h3>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                </div><!-- End of Panel Heading  -->            
                  <div class="panel-body">
                  </br>
                    <div class="row"> 

                <!--/.row1 -->          
                <!-- Display each comic by id -->       
                    </br>
                    <?php foreach($comics as $list) : ?>
                      <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <?= ($list['image'] <> " " ? "<img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/{$list['image']}'/>" : "") ?>          

                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                <?= ($list['name'] <> "" ? $list['name'] : "") ?> #<?= ($list['issue'] <> "" ? $list['issue'] : "") ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  -->             <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->            <?php endforeach; ?>            </div>      </div>  </br><!-- end of row  -->        <!-- Else show this message if user has no entries
-->
            <?php
            }else {
                ?>
                <p><b>You haven't posted any comic yet!</b></p>
            <?php } ?> 
       </div> <!-- end of panel body  -->
     </div> <!-- end of panel panel-default  -->     <!--/.row1-collapse -->      </div> <!-- end of col-md-12  -->   </div> <!-- End of Row  -->  </div>  <!-- /.container -->  <?php require('template/footer.phtml') ?>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding-top: 75px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
.navbar a{
    color:#fff !important;
}

.comic-box {

    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding: 5px;
}
.cart-block{
    background:#333;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.panel-list a{
    display:block;
    color:#666;
}

.panel-list .panel-heading h3{
    padding:5px;
    font-size:18px;
}

.panel-heading-green{
    background:#3b7e14 !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}

.panel-heading-dark{
    background:#333333 !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}

.comic{
    display:relative;
}

.comic-title{

    text-align:center;
    background:#333;
    color:#fff;
    width:70%;
}

.comic img{
    width:70%;
}


.comic-add{
    padding: 5px;
    margin:5px auto 20px auto;
    width:30%;
    text-align:center;
}

.parabox{
    padding: 5px;
    display: box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
}
.details img{
    width:100%;
}

.footer{
    background:#333;
    color:#fff;
    height:70px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20px;
    display: inline;
}
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

HTML Generated

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>My Comics</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()" style="background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">My Comics</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
                 <!-- If email is does not equal email in database then remain in index page -->
                                                        <!-- If email does equal the one given in database login to profile -->
                                                      <!-- Display logout button along with users email -->
                                    <div class="navbar-search navbar-brand pull-right">
                                                    <form action="logout.php" method="post">
                               <!-- Welcome message for user with logout button --> 
                                Welcome lennyd1992@gmail.com                                <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="submit" class="btn-danger"/>
                            </form>
                                            </div>
               <!-- Login Form for users -->
                            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <!-- Start of Col Div -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!--/.Panel for Comics -->
            <!-- Single button -->
            <!-- Count for Comics -->           
                        </br> 
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-green"><h3 class="panel-title">My Comics</h3>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                </div><!-- End of Panel Heading  -->            
                  <div class="panel-body">
                  </br>
                    <div class="row"> 

                <!--/.row1 -->          
                <!-- Display each comic by id -->       
                    </br>
                                          <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/flash8.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                The Flash #8                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/justice6.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Justice League #6                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/starwarsforce5.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Star Wars The Force Awakens #5                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/starwarshansolo4.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Star Wars Han Solo #4                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/walkingdead100.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                The Walking Dead #100                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/walkingdead150.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                The Walking Dead #150                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/walkingdead115.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                The Walking Dead #115                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/captainamerica223.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Captain America #223                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/avengers227.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                The Avengers #227                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/teenage62.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles #62                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/superman7.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Superman #7                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/thestarwars.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                The Star Wars #1                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/starwars23.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Star Wars #23                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/teenage62sub.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles #62                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/xmen927.JPG'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                X-Men92 #7                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/teenage63.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles #63                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/teenage61.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles #61                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/teenage2.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles #2                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/spider-dead9.jpg'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                Spider-Man/Deadpool #9                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->
                                  <div class="col-md-3 comic">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img style='max-width:200px; max-height:250px;' src='Images/blackmondaymurders3.png'/>                    
                            </a>
                            <div class="comic-title">
                                The Black Monday Murders #3                            </div>
                            <div class="comic-add">
                           </div>       
                     </div>  
                <!-- End of Col-MD-3 Comic  --> 
            <!-- End of Foreach Statement for Comics -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </br><!-- end of row  -->
         <!-- Else show this message if user has no entries -->

       </div> <!-- end of panel body  -->
     </div> <!-- end of panel panel-default  -->
     <!--/.row1-collapse -->  
   </div> <!-- end of col-md-12  -->
  </div> <!-- End of Row  -->
 </div>  <!-- /.container -->   
<br>
<br>


 <footer class="footer">

        <p class="text-muted">My Comics &copy; 2016, All Rights Reserved</p>

    </footer>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using MVC for my project as well. Any ideas on how to rectify this problem ?

Comment: add your CSS and html generated

Comment: Hi apologies I have done so now

Comment: Typical clearfix issue, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410779/why-does-bootstrap-grid-improperly-stack-these-elements/41410858#41410858 also, if you can avoid those `<br>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does bootstrap grid improperly stack these elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410779/why-does-bootstrap-grid-improperly-stack-these-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are behaving unexpectedly because of their varied height parameters.
Your possible options are to use any one of the three:

1. Manage your rows with clearfix
2. Use a layout management library like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).
3. Fix the height of all your column cards.